# How to read excel files from online zip link in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an online link which is updated with a zip file everyday. The zip file contains a folder and within that the xls file I want to read into pandas

I tried using zipfile module.

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('http://xxxxx/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx.zip')
```

But it gave an error:

> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'http://xxxxx/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx.zip'

Also only read csv seems to have compression attribute

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `urllib` and `io`:

```
import zipfile
from urllib.request import urlopen
# from urllib import urlopen  # for python 2

import io

zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(urlopen(url).read()))
```

As another option you can pass `compression='gzip'` argument into `pd.read_csv` method.

Comment: What is the embedded file is an .xlsx extension?  pd.read_excel doesn't seem to like this.